# Filter Posts depending ID of categorie with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small task where I have a mysql table "blog".It contains a column "ID_CAT". Each field of ID_CAT contains diiferent values of category for one single article like "22,44,33,55" .
I want to filter the posts of blog depending on the category choosing . i pass the ID_CAT choosing into URL and GET methode in the included page like that

```
<a class="rotated_link" href="?cat='.$categorie->getIDCategorie().'">'.$categorie->getNomCategorie().'</a>
```

then the page included like that

```
$id_categorie = $_GET["cat"];
if (isset($id_categorie)) {

  foreach(Article::getAllArticlebycategorie($id_categorie) as $all){
                $article= new Article($all->ID_BLOG);
                $img=Image::getImageByArticle($article->getIDarticle());
                $tblCat=explode(',',$article->getIDCategorie());
                    echo '<li class="li_blog_post">';
                            echo'<img class="img_post_mini" src="img/file/'.$img.'" style="width:100%; height:150px; border:1PX solid #9D9D9D;" />';
                            echo'<span class="post_title0">'.$article->getTitlearticle().'</span>';
                            echo'<span class="tag_post"><img src="img/tag.png" style="width:16px; height:16px;"/>';
                    foreach($tblCat as $catt){
                        $categoriea = new Categorie($catt);

                    echo '<a class="tag_lable" href="">'.$categoriea->getNomCategorie().'</a> </span>';
                    }
                    echo'<p class="post_prev">'.substr($article->getArticle(), 0, 410).'&nbsp;...</p>';
                    echo'<span class="date">le&nbsp;'.$article->getDatearticle().'</span> <span class="view_more"><a class="test" href="?article='.$article->getIDarticle().'">voire les détails</a></span>';
                   echo '</li>';
                }  

}
```

the probleme is when i choose for example ID_CAT=4 , the function getAllArticlebycategorie returne the posts only if the number 4 is the first value in column ID_CAT (4,33,50)-> selected (3,4,10)-> not selected .
the function :

```
public static function getAllArticlebycategorie($id_categorie){
    global $db;
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog WHERE ID_CAT='.$id_categorie);
    $req->execute();
    return $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and since you're using PDO utilize parameterized query.

Therefore change

```
$req = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog WHERE ID_CAT='.$id_categorie);
$req->execute();
```

to

```
$req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$id_categorie', ID_CAT)");
$req->execute(array(':id_categorie' => $id_categorie));
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/295c0/2)** for you to play with `FIND_IN_SET()`